# ?tags=... query string present in Google search result; URL doesn't link to tagged page

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, google

I just made a Google search for "ux stackexchange forms". The first result correctly points to `.../tagged/forms`, but the second result points to `...?tags=forms`, which has no effect:

> [image: Picture of text]

The link, https://ux.stackexchange.com/?tags=forms, takes me to the home page for the UX Stack Exchange site. I'm guessing this is an old URL format which is no longer in use?

Interestingly, I completely skipped the first link when reading the search results, as the term "forms" is more prominent in the second link.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is due to the tag navigation system used in previous year:

[image]

Which links to the `?tags=` like navigation things. Google may be caching olden navigation links but now such navigations are no longer being used and that's why you're getting home page due to no effect of `?tags=`.

Comment: oh, crap... You're right, it is those tags. But those aren't part of new-nav - they're live *right now* - just visit the site while logged out.

Comment: @Shog9 oh, yes, it means that feature is for (outside) visitors only.